# packages can't be installed because of dependencies problem

Tags: apt, dependencies

I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed. After adding debian bullseye to the source.list there are some updates that i cant install:

[image]

If i try to install them, there are error msg because there are dependencies(python3.10.6.1 already installed on the system):

> The following packages have violated dependencies: python3-systemd
> : Depends on: python3 (< 3.10) but 3.10.6-1~22.04 is installed

I tried to install them using altitude aswell. Altitude suggests me to keep the current installed packets.
What is the best practice here?

Comment: ubuntu and debian packages are not compatible. The fast way is to save important data and install new.

Comment: can i just skip this specific packages since upgrading them require downgrade of certain packages? like upgrading python3-systemd requires downgrading of my current python3.10 to python 3.9

Comment: Sooner or later your system will be brocken. Many systemtools require the correct python3 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations, you have created a classic [Frankendebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian)

Both Debian and Ubuntu strongly (very strongly!) advise against mixing Debian and Ubuntu sources.

While both use deb packages, they often don't use the same *versions* of those packages. The result are version conflicts exactly like you are encountering.

In Debian-based systems, versions are important. They govern dependencies. Debian-based systems lock to a single common set of versions -- that's the definition of a Debian (and Ubuntu) release. When you change versions, you break the system.

Adding a wrong-release source = Adding wrong version = Break the system.

The #1 step to repairing the damage is to remove the Debian source from your system.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :) Just learned a new word "Frankendebian"..... thx again